# How to re-route request from one route to another in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm building dynamic routing system in Web API service.

For example, service might have several routes (I don't know exact count and prefixes on application start). I want to create some custom route that will decide which route to choose (some kind of internal redirection to another route), initialize it on the first request and pass the request to it.

I've tried to inherit from HttpRoute and override GetRouteData, but for some reason after changing the route in IHttpRouteData server returns me 406 Not Accepted status code. Simple example with only one route for substitution:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) // on Application_Start
{
    WebApiConfig.Configuration.Routes.Add("InitRoute", new LazyInitializationRoute("myservice/{*params}"));
}

public class LazyInitializationRoute : HttpRoute
{
    private static bool _initialized = false;

    public LazyInitializationRoute(string routeTemplate)
        : base(routeTemplate) { }

    public override IHttpRouteData GetRouteData(string virtualPathRoot, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        IHttpRouteData baseRouteData = base.GetRouteData(virtualPathRoot, request);
        if (baseRouteData == null) return null;

        if (!_initialized)
        {
            WebApiConfig.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("MyRoute", "myservice");
            _initialized = true;
        }
        IHttpRoute odataRoute = WebApiConfig.Configuration.Routes["MyRoute"];
        var values = baseRouteData.Values;
        IHttpRouteData routeData = values == null ? new HttpRouteData(odataRoute) : new HttpRouteData(odataRoute, new HttpRouteValueDictionary(values));
        return routeData;
    }
}
```

Please help. How can I achieve desired behavior?

Comment: What is your solution intended to do that isn't already offered by the base routing process? you can parse variables as routing parameters already, so what do your URLs look like that makes them need to be processed in a different manner?

Comment: First of all, I need lazy initialization for my routes (I'm using Web API OData, and in my case it is impossible to build EDM model for OData route on Application_Start). Secondary, my service should support several metadata documents that are completely different; Web API OData is unable to provide this functionality on one route, each OData route has it's own metadata document and EDM model.